# Is it true that I can use any C++ packages/libraries in R through Rcpp?

Tags: c++, r, api, rcpp

I am recently using Rcpp, which is utterly amazing tool for R users. I am curious and ambitious to think about whether it is true that I can easily use any C++ packages/libraries in R through Rcpp.

Comment: Yes it is.  One real-world caveat is that the _library you wish to build against_ must also be present.  Hence, easier for something like `libxml` than for `libBrandNewNotInstalledAnywhere`.

Comment: Just how the R API allowed to link (as C code) to it. You may need to write your type converters though.  All documented.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel many thanks! is there a good tutorial that went through the whole process to link R to an existing cpp library?